# (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /guides/{guideID} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid !=null;
    }
  }
}
```

[this is the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRRF2.png)

it not giving me error if i use wildcard on whole collection
but it gives error If i gave a path

Comment: Rules by themselves don't do anything.  They only take affect when paired with app code that makes a query.  Please edit the question to show the app code that isn't working the way you expect.  We should be able to see how your code matches these rules.  You should also show that a user is signed in at the time of the query.

Comment: thks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection name is `guide` (singular) and you're trying to match on `guides` (plural).

Comment: thks a lot i was trying it a lot for 3 hours

Comment: <3 You have no idea how many hours I've spent debugging because of typos!